git fails to read password when git-gui window is open (Windows 10)
Recently I have started getting this error but only if I also have a git-gui window open.
The same command works fine if the git-gui window is closed.
I am running git v2.47.0 on Windows 10 inside Windows Terminal.
Git credential.helper is set to 'manager'
This used to work fine before, not sure exactly when it started, probably a few weeks ago.
Any idea what is going on and how to prevent it?
# git fetch --all
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 5)
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://shreedhark@github.com': No such file or directory

Here is a screenshot of the commands and responses


Assuming you are using the latest Git for Windows v2.47.0.windows.2 (Oct. 2024), this could be a side effect of a Git GUI bug discussed in this thread.
It involves setting SSH_ASKPASS to c:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-askpass.exe, and involves SSH URL, but git-askpass.exe is also used for HTTPS URL.

Yes, I am using that exact same version. I will look more into the git-askpass
